# Is there a way to have Azure Blob Storage failover be activated through a release pipeline?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I was trying to activate the failover using the powershell option in a release pipeline, however I get his error:

> Invoke-AzStorageAccountFailover : Windows PowerShell is in
> NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available.

Is there anyway to get around this, or any plans to extend this functionality? We have a lot of storage accounts in the same region so we are trying to automate our disaster recovery strategy.

Comment: Have you tried running this Cmdlet with `-AsJob` parameter?

Comment: When running with -AsJob it completes with a blocked status

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `-Force` switch, to confirm that the cmdlet should just run, without an attempt of waiting for any *Read and Prompt* ?

Works for me, in the Azure DevOps pipeline:

```
$StorageAccount = Invoke-AzStorageAccountFailover `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
    -Name $StorageAccountName `
    -Force
```